# Calculate distance in km to nearest points (given in lat/long) using ArcGIS DEsktop and/or R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, r, distance, units

I have two point datasets in ArcGIS, both of which are given in WGS84 lat/lon co-ordinates and the points are spread across the whole world. I would like to find the nearest point in Dataset A to each point in Dataset B, and get the distance between them in kilometres.

This seems like a perfect use of the Near tool, but that gives me results in the co-ordinate system of the input points: that is, decimal degrees. I know I could re-project the data, but I gather ([from this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5579/what-is-the-right-solution-and-map-projection-to-compute-distances-between-poi)) that it is difficult (if not impossible) to find a projection that will give accurate distances all over the world.

The answers to that question suggest using the Haversine formula to calculate distances using the latitude-longitude co-ordinates directly. Is there a way to do this and get a result in km using ArcGIS? If not, what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this isn't an ArcGIS solution, your problem can be solved in R by exporting your points from Arc and using the `spDists`  function from the `sp` package.  The function finds the distances between a reference point(s) and a matrix of points, in kilometers if you set `longlat=T`.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
library(sp)
## Sim up two sets of 100 points, we'll call them set a and set b:
a <- SpatialPoints(coords = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, -87.5), y = rnorm(100, 30)), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
b <- SpatialPoints(coords = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, -88.5), y = rnorm(100, 30.5)), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

## Find the distance from each point in a to each point in b, store
##    the results in a matrix.
results <- spDists(a, b, longlat=T)
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems like the most realistic solution. Looking at the docs it seems that I can only do this between a reference point and a set of other points, so I would have to do it in a loop to go through all of my points. Do you know of a more efficient way to do this in R?

Comment: No looping needed, you can give the function two sets of points and it will return a matrix with distances between each combination of points.  Edited answer to include example code.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an ArcGIS solution, but using a Round Earth data model in a spatial database would do the trick. Calculating earth distance in database supporting this would be pretty easy. I can suggest you two readings:

http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html

http://blog.safe.com/2012/08/round-earth-data-in-oracle-postgis-and-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

You need a distance calculation that works with Lat/Long. [Vincenty](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) is the one I would use (0.5mm accuracy). I have played with it before, and it is not too hard to use.

The code is a bit long, but it works. Given two points in WGS, it will return a distance in meters.

You can use this as a Python script in ArcGIS, or wrap it around another script that simply iterates over the two Point Shapefiles and builds a distance matrix for you. Or, it is probably easier to feed the results of GENERATE_NEAR_TABLE with finding the 2-3 nearest features (to avoid complications of earth's curvature).

```
import math

ellipsoids = {
    #name        major(m)   minor(m)            flattening factor
    'WGS-84':   (6378137,   6356752.3142451793, 298.25722356300003),
    'GRS-80':   (6378137,   6356752.3141403561, 298.25722210100002),
    'GRS-67':   (6378160,   6356774.5160907144, 298.24716742700002),

}

def distanceVincenty(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, ellipsoid='WGS-84'):
    """Computes the Vicenty distance (in meters) between two points
    on the earth. Coordinates need to be in decimal degrees.
    """
    # Check if we got numbers
    # Removed to save space
    # Check if we know about the ellipsoid
    # Removed to save space
    major, minor, ffactor = ellipsoids[ellipsoid]
    # Convert degrees to radians
    x1 = math.radians(lat1)
    y1 = math.radians(long1)
    x2 = math.radians(lat2)
    y2 = math.radians(long2)
    # Define our flattening f
    f = 1 / ffactor
    # Find delta X
    deltaX = y2 - y1
    # Calculate U1 and U2
    U1 = math.atan((1 - f) * math.tan(x1))
    U2 = math.atan((1 - f) * math.tan(x2))
    # Calculate the sin and cos of U1 and U2
    sinU1 = math.sin(U1)
    cosU1 = math.cos(U1)
    sinU2 = math.sin(U2)
    cosU2 = math.cos(U2)
    # Set initial value of L
    L = deltaX
    # Set Lambda equal to L
    lmbda = L
    # Iteration limit - when to stop if no convergence
    iterLimit = 100
    while abs(lmbda) > 10e-12 and iterLimit >= 0:
        # Calculate sine and cosine of lmbda
        sin_lmbda = math.sin(lmbda)
        cos_lmbda = math.cos(lmbda)
        # Calculate the sine of sigma
        sin_sigma = math.sqrt(
                (cosU2 * sin_lmbda) ** 2 + 
                (cosU1 * sinU2 - 
                 sinU1 * cosU2 * cos_lmbda) ** 2
        )
        if sin_sigma == 0.0:
            # Concident points - distance is 0
            return 0.0
        # Calculate the cosine of sigma
        cos_sigma = (
                    sinU1 * sinU2 + 
                    cosU1 * cosU2 * cos_lmbda
        )
        # Calculate sigma
        sigma = math.atan2(sin_sigma, cos_sigma)
        # Calculate the sine of alpha
        sin_alpha = (cosU1 * cosU2 * math.sin(lmbda)) / (sin_sigma)
        # Calculate the square cosine of alpha
        cos_alpha_sq = 1 - sin_alpha ** 2
        # Calculate the cosine of 2 sigma
        cos_2sigma = cos_sigma - ((2 * sinU1 * sinU2) / cos_alpha_sq)
        # Identify C
        C = (f / 16.0) * cos_alpha_sq * (4.0 + f * (4.0 - 3 * cos_alpha_sq))
        # Recalculate lmbda now
        lmbda = L + ((1.0 - C) * f * sin_alpha * (sigma + C * sin_sigma * (cos_2sigma + C * cos_sigma * (-1.0 + 2 * cos_2sigma ** 2)))) 
        # If lambda is greater than pi, there is no solution
        if (abs(lmbda) > math.pi):
            raise ValueError("No solution can be found.")
        iterLimit -= 1
    if iterLimit == 0 and lmbda > 10e-12:
        raise ValueError("Solution could not converge.")
    # Since we converged, now we can calculate distance
    # Calculate u squared
    u_sq = cos_alpha_sq * ((major ** 2 - minor ** 2) / (minor ** 2))
    # Calculate A
    A = 1 + (u_sq / 16384.0) * (4096.0 + u_sq * (-768.0 + u_sq * (320.0 - 175.0 * u_sq)))
    # Calculate B
    B = (u_sq / 1024.0) * (256.0 + u_sq * (-128.0 + u_sq * (74.0 - 47.0 * u_sq)))
    # Calculate delta sigma
    deltaSigma = B * sin_sigma * (cos_2sigma + 0.25 * B * (cos_sigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos_2sigma ** 2) - 1.0/6.0 * B * cos_2sigma * (-3.0 + 4.0 * sin_sigma ** 2) * (-3.0 + 4.0 * cos_2sigma ** 2)))
    # Calculate s, the distance
    s = minor * A * (sigma - deltaSigma)
    # Return the distance
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

I made similar experiences with small datasets using the Point Distance tool. Doing so, you cannot automatically find the nearest points in your Dataset A, but at least get a table output with useful km or m results. In a next step you could select the shortest distance to each point of Dataset B out of the table.

But this approach would depend on the amount of points in your datasets. It might not work properly with large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I can't see how that will help me. According to the docs (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001r000000) "the distance is in the linear unit of the input features coordinate system.", which as my input features are in lat/lon will surely give me results in decimal degrees? (I haven't got a machine with ArcGIS on it here to test)

Comment: In this case, I would probably use a "quick and dirty" solution by adding X and Y fields in your datatable and click on Calculate Geometry choosing X and Y in meter. If not possible to pick this option, change the coordinate system of your MXD.

I was working on a project before, where my client wanted long/lat, X/Y and Gauss-Krueger R/H values all in each Shape file. To avoid complicated calculation, simply changing projections and calculate geometry was the most easy way it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need high-precision and robust geodesic measurements, use [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/), which is natively written in several programming languages, including C++, Java, MATLAB, Python, etc.

See [C. F. F. Karney (2013) "Algorithms for geodesics"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z) for a literary reference. Note that these algorithms are more robust and accurate than Vincenty's algorithm, for instance near antipodes.

To calculate distance in metres between two points, get the `s12` distance attribute from the [inverse geodesic solution](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1Geodesic.html#ad7e59a242125a35a95c96cdb20573081). E.g., with the [geographiclib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib) package for Python

```py
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
g = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(-41.32, 174.81, 40.96, -5.50)
print(g)  # shows:
{'a12': 179.6197069334283,
 'azi1': 161.06766998615873,
 'azi2': 18.825195123248484,
 'lat1': -41.32,
 'lat2': 40.96,
 'lon1': 174.81,
 'lon2': -5.5,
 's12': 19959679.26735382}
```

Or make a convenience function, which also converts from metres to kilometres:

```py
dist_km = lambda a, b: Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1])['s12'] / 1000.0
a = (-41.32, 174.81)
b = (40.96, -5.50)
print(dist_km(a, b))  # 19959.6792674 km
```

Now to find the closest point between lists `A` and `B`, each with 100 points:

```py
from random import uniform
from itertools import product
A = [(uniform(-90, 90), uniform(-180, 180)) for x in range(100)]
B = [(uniform(-90, 90), uniform(-180, 180)) for x in range(100)]
a_min = b_min = min_dist = None
for a, b in product(A, B):
    d = dist_km(a, b)
    if min_dist is None or d < min_dist:
        min_dist = d
        a_min = a
        b_min = b

print('%.3f km between %s and %s' % (min_dist, a_min, b_min))
```

> 22.481 km between (84.57916462672875, 158.67545706102192) and (84.70326937581333, 156.9784597422855)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody wants to exchange the existing `sp` solution for one making use of `sf`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

set.seed(42)

# create two sets of 100 points each
a <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, -87.5), y = rnorm(100, 30)) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
b <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, -88.5), y = rnorm(100, 30.5)) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

# get the full distance matrix
results <- st_distance(a, b)
```