# Geodesic measurements for short distances throughout US?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, measurements, geodesic

My ArcGIS experience has been limited to working on large-scale maps with planar projections. I'm moving to a project in which I want to calculate the distance between pro sports facilities throughout the U.S. and their city's respective downtown/central business district (both defined as geocoded points).

My primary interest is in relative distances, and my question is whether using a geographic coordinate system for US map points and using "Near" to calculate geodesic distances between stadia and downtowns is a sound approach to avoiding issues that would arise from calculating distance based on a projection of the US?

Comment: I now believe there are **two** questions being asked here. Rather than make any more edits, i've asked how to clean it up, over at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/how-to-make-an-invalid-question-valid-by-splitting-it-into-two-related-questio

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that the answer is no: what you mean to do is correct but it will not work like this in ArcGIS with Near.

From the help, you can read that :

> The distances calculated by this tool are in the unit of the
>   coordinate system of the input features. If your input is in a
>   geographic coordinate system and you want output distances to be
>   measured in a linear unit (as opposed to decimal degrees), you must
>   first project your input to a projected coordinate system using the
>   Project tool. For best results, use an equidistant projection or a
>   projection intended for your study area (UTM, for example)

in other words, if you use a geographic coordinate system, near will work as if it was a cartesian coordinate system.

You should instead use the Haversine approximation (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61924/python-gdal-degrees-to-meters-without-reprojecting/61985#61985) ) or, better, the [Vicenty's formula](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32981/calculate-distance-in-km-to-nearest-points-given-in-lat-long-using-arcgis/33666#33666) to find your solution (see @Michalis Avraam's answer)

Comment: Thanks for this, everyone. The python script for the Haversine approximation looks like it should be more than sufficient. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

**No**, if using the ArcGIS "Near" tool because, even if the coordinate system is geographic/geodetic, it does *not* calculate geodesic distances; it merely treats those geographic coordinates as though they were projected and thus gives results that cannot be compared across the US.

---

**Yes**, if you correctly calculate geodesic distances using geographic coordinates between points in or near downtown -- and you compare those with similar calculations made in completely different cities across the US -- you will have sound results. Doing it correctly means using spherical trigonometry (or some other geodetic technique).

Conversely, if you merely use plane coordinates -- taken from a single, national map projection -- and plane geometry for the same types of comparisons, you will not get sound results.

There are many questions that deal with such problems/methods on this site.

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods to calculate geodesic distances such as the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae). These formulae are commonly used. The [inverse Vincenty distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Inverse_problem) is the more accurate method to calculate the geodesic distance and is used in Google Maps, but it is slow.

Comment: (1) I believe that Google Maps merely calculates the great circle distance (with a mean earth radius of 6371.009 km) instead of the geodesic distance. (2) It is an often-repeated myth that calculating the geodesic distance is slow.  In fact the calculation takes about 2 us with compiled code on a present-day desktop computer -- maybe 5 times longer with "interpreted" code like JavaScript.  In many applications, this counts as instantaneous.