# JTS - Java Topology Suite - Calculate radius from a given point

Tags: java, topology, jts-topology-suite

From point A, I want to check if a point B is within a certain radius from A.
How calculate it usindo JTS?

I tried this:

```
Coordinate posicaoAtual = new Coordinate(-12.974900375893823, -38.48034163207694); 
Localidade localidade = new Localidade(-12.976353604547635, -38.47492356986686);
Geometry ponto = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(localidade.getCoordenada());
Geometry pos = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(posicaoAtual);
Geometry raio = ponto.buffer(100.0, 8); // HERE
System.out.println(raio.contains(pos));
```

My doubt is to know which the distance unit from the first parameter of the buffer method?

Comment: the buffer distance is in the same units as the coordinates - probably degrees in your example.

Comment: How to convert degrees in meters? Because the user will send the distance in meters.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b/4909#4909

Comment: Correcting my question: 
Geometry raio = ponto.buffer(METER_TO_DEGREE, 8); 
The buffer method receive in degree. How convert meters in degree?

Comment: I use this calc: (PARAMETER_IN_METER * 0.00001)/1.1132
Is it acceptable?

Comment: You can't simply scale from metres to degrees or vice-versa. You need to project your coordinates. You can roll your own or use an existing library, such as [this](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) or [this](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/). Both of these are ports of Proj.4. Once you have projected coordinates, you can use JTS to your heart's content.

Answer (score 1):

JTS is only for cartesian coordinates, your's are ellipsoidal. So I would say the answer is "do not use JTS for this". You would need write a method for the calculation yourself.