# What is unit of Shapely length attribute?

Tags: python, line, shapely, length, units

I'm doing a very simple calculation of the length of a Polyline using shapely:

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString

... 
xy_list = [map(float, e) for e in xy_intm]
line = LineString(xy_list)
s = '%s,%s,%s' % (fr, to, line.length)
```

My coordinates are in WGS84. I can't seem to find any information about Shapely's length attribute. What is the unit of the length attribute? Is there an easy way to convert to km or meters?

Comment: Can you provide the coordinates and length for two sample shapes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [alfaciano](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/22405/afalciano) says in shapely, the distance is the Euclidean Distance or Linear distance between two points on a plane and not the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between two points on a sphere.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
import math


point1 = Point(50.67,4.62)
point2 = Point(51.67, 4.64)

# Euclidean Distance
def Euclidean_distance(point1,point2):
     return math.sqrt((point2.x()-point1.x())**2 + (point2.y()-point1.y())**2)

print Euclidean_distance(point1,point2)
1.00019998 # distance in degrees (coordinates of the points in degrees)

# with Shapely
print point1.distance(point2)
1.0001999800039989 #distance in degrees (coordinates of the points in degrees)
```

For the great-circle distance, you need to use algorithms as the law of cosines or the Haversine formula (look at [Why is law of cosines more preferable than haversine when calculating distance between two latitude-longitude points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b)) or use the module [pyproj](http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/) that performs geodetic calculations.

```py
# law of cosines
distance = math.acos(math.sin(math.radians(point1.y))*math.sin(math.radians(point2.y))+math.cos(math.radians(point1.y))*math.cos(math.radians(point2.y))*math.cos(math.radians(point2.x)-math.radians(point1.x)))*6371
print "{0:8.4f}".format(distance)
110.8544 # in km
# Haversine formula
dLat = math.radians(point2.y) - math.radians(point1.y)
dLon = math.radians(point2.x) - math.radians(point1.x)
a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(point1.y)) * math.cos(math.radians(point2.y)) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2)
distance = 6371 * 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
print "{0:8.4f}".format(distance)distance
110.8544 #in km

# with pyproj
import pyproj
geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')
angle1,angle2,distance = geod.inv(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y)
print "{0:8.4f}".format(distance/1000)
110.9807 #in km
```

You can test the result at [Longitude Latitude Distance Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/lldistcalc.html)

[image]

Comment: Great answer, Gene! Many thanks for your very detailed explanation.

Comment: Indeed, great answer. If I'm not mistaken there is another python package called `geopy` that has implemented a great-circle distance and Vincenty distance calculating.

Comment: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted#Calculating_distances)'s some details about geodesic distance calculation with `geopy`.

Answer (score 23):

> **Coordinate Systems**
>
> [...]
> *Shapely does not support coordinate system transformations. All
> operations on two or more features presume that the features exist in
> the same Cartesian plane.*

Source: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#coordinate-systems

`shapely` is completely agnostic in reference to SRS. Therefore, the length attribute is expressed in the same unit of coordinates of your linestring, i.e. degrees.
In fact:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import LineString
>>> line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
>>> line.length
1.4142135623730951
```

Instead, if you want to express length in meters, you have to transform your geometries from WGS84 to a projected SRS using **[pyproj](http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)** (or, better, execute geodesic distance calculation, see Gene's answer). In detail, since version **1.2.18** (`shapely.__version__`), `shapely` supports the **geometry transform functions** ( http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.html#module-shapely.ops) that we can use it in conjunction with `pyproj`. Here's a quick example:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj

line1 = LineString([(15.799406, 40.636069), (15.810173,40.640246)])
print(str(line1.length) + " degrees")
# 0.0115488362184 degrees

# Geometry transform function based on pyproj.transform
project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj('EPSG:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj('EPSG:32633'))

line2 = transform(project, line1)
print(str(line2.length) + " meters")
# 1021.77585965 meters
```

Answer (score 13):

You can now use shapely w/ pyproj to get geodesic length in meters:

From: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.geometry_length

```
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
line_string = LineString([Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)])
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")
f"{geod.geometry_length(line_string):.3f}"
'313588.397'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/), which is written in many programming languages. The [Python implementation](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/) is pure Python and does not have any dependencies, so it is easy to install: `pip install geographiclib`.

Here is an example:

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

geod = Geodesic.WGS84
# parameters: lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2
g = geod.Inverse(4.62, 50.67, 4.64, 51.67)
print("The distance is {:.3f} m.".format(g['s12']))
# The distance is 110980.677 m.
```

Or with shapely points:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

# order is: lon, lat
p1 = Point(50.67, 4.62)
p2 = Point(51.67, 4.64)
g = geod.Inverse(p1.y, p1.x, p2.y, p2.x)
print("The distance is {:.3f} m.".format(g['s12']))
# The distance is 110980.677 m.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update of the [most popular answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80898/87707) using the latest version of pyproj (presently 3.3.1), and with some extra tips for different co-ordinate systems.

As mentioned shapely is agnostic to coordinate system, so use pyproj to convert to a co-ordinate system in metres.

```
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:32633")

line1 = LineString([(15.799406, 40.636069), (15.810173,40.640246)])
line2 = transform(transformer.transform, line1)
print(str(line2.length) + " meters")
# 1400.1203731431115 meters
```

If like me you are using co-ordinates in (lng, lat) or (x,y) form, then you'll need to add a parameter to the transformer creation method:

```
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:32633", always_xy=True)
```

In this case I'm converting to the co-ordinate system used in the answer I linked, but your co-ordinates might be in a different part of the world. You can use https://epsg.io/ to search for your particular country or co-ordinate system. In my case I had co-ordinates in Mexico, so I used ["epsg:4484"](https://epsg.io/4484):

```
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:4484", always_xy=True)
```