# differences in distance between shapely and geopy

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapely, fiona, geopy

I am getting totally different distances from shapely and geopy. On one hand - *it makes total sense, shapely measures on a plane and geopy measures on a spheroid*. But the differences are so dramatic, I am wondering if something is truly off here.

Using:

- Shapely 1.3.2
- geopy 1.9.1
- Fiona 1.l.5

my prj (for shapely/fiona) IS Web-Merc EPSG: 3857 (w/o flattening):

```
     >>print input_crs
     >>{u'a': 6378137, u'lon_0': 0, u'k': 1, u'y_0': 0, u'b': 6378137, u'proj': u'merc', u'x_0': 0, u'units': u'm', u'no_defs': True}
     >>print to_string(input_crs)
     >>+a=6378137 +b=6378137 +k=1 +lon_0 +no_defs +proj=merc +units=m +x_0 +y_0
```

Test Pts (*Arizona/N.Mex general area):

```
city: POINT (-12352678.6153664 3384049.040913342)
capital: POINT (-12318614.85118365 3417715.06365641)
```

My code, using shapely for *.buffer* and Vincenty for the ellipsoid measure (geopy)

```
def evaluate_point(city_pt, capital_pts):

    #tests whether the capitals are within a certain distance of a
    #city point 

    # set the ellipsoid for measurement
    distance.VincentyDistance.ELLIPSOID = 'WGS-84'
    d = distance.distance

    # create a wkt obj of city pt
    city_wkt = dumps(city_pt)

    dist = 300000

    # create a shapely obj of all the capitals
    for pt in capital_pts:
        # create a shapely obj of all the captial_pts
        capital_pt = shape(pt['geometry'])
         # create a wkt obj of the admin1_pt
        capital_to_measure = dumps(capital_pt)

        ## BUFFER USING SHAPELY - DIST = 300000 meters due to prj
        capital_buffer = capital_pt.buffer(dist)
        # city_pt is a shapely obj
        if city_pt.within(capital_buffer):
            distance_between_pts = d(capital_to_measure, city_wkt).meters
            print"within the buffer" + " " + str(distance_between_pts)
            print "city: " + city_wkt
            print "capital: " + capital_to_measure

        else:
            print "outside the buffer"
```

FOR this data I get this:

```
city: POINT (-12352678.6153664 3384049.040913342)
capital: POINT (-12318614.85118365 3417715.06365641)


   within the buffer # shapely buffer set to (300000 meters) 
   14815370.7894 # Vincenty ellipsoid measured distance reported in meters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For calculate the Vincenty distance, you need coordinates in longitude, latitude (degrees) and you choose WGS84  (look at with [Geopy:distance](http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#module-geopy.distance))

2) The coordinates of your points are in meters:  **u'units': u'm'** (according to your Proj4 string (+a=6378137 +b=6378137 +k=1 +lon_0 +no_defs +proj=merc +units=m +x_0 +y_0)

As your coordinates are in meters, you can use the Shapely distance (Euclidean Distance or Linear distance) between two points ([What is the unit the shapely length attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80881/what-is-the-unit-the-shapely-length-attribute))

```
for pt in capital_pts:
    capital_pt = shape(pt['geometry'])
    capital_to_measure = capital_pt.wkt
    capital_buffer = capital_pt.buffer(dist)
    if city_pt.within(capital_buffer):
        distance_between_pts =  capital_to_measure.distance(city_pt) # in meters
```

3) If you really want to use the Geopy Vincenty distance you need to change the projection of your data (with [Pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj), for example)

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
your_proj = Proj('+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ')
wgs84 = Proj(init="epsg:4326")
city = Point(-12352678.6153664,3384049.040913342) # shapely point
long, lat =  transform(your_proj, wgs84 ,city.x, city.y)
print(Point(long,lat).wkt)
'POINT (-110.966 29.22957857026954)'
```